# gpresult /v and rsop.msc shows reverse values for GPO's on windows 10

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-10

In our domain we have a situation that keeps us confused:

We have created a GPO on our 2012 R2 AD and applied it to our windows 10 workstations.

When we examine the workstations with the "gpresult /v" commandline tool, we get settings that are the reverse of the GPO setting.

When we examine the workstations with the "rsop.msc" tool, we get the same settings that are in the GPO.

Below is a screenshot of the two tools executing on the same workstations, notice the "Allow Cortana above search bar" as an example of the reverse settings.

Hope someone can help us.

Best regards,

[image: Screendump from test machine]

[image: Screendump of the GPO]

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out:
when gpresult reports "enabled" it simply means that the GPO itself is "active" on the machine.

The Value is the important one: If the first value number is "0" it means it have been disabled.

Comment: Welcome to the fun, fun world of Group Policy, where double negatives, triple negatives, and enabling a setting to disable it are all considered a normal mode of operating! :)